# What about the digital mode ROS causes some to consider it spread spectrum?

Tags: united-states, legal, modes, digital-modes

The FCC disallows amateur spread spectrum communications below 220MHz.  At the moment the relatively new digital mode, ROS, is considered, by some, to be spread spectrum.  So this mode is getting little to no use in the US.

It doesn't seem much different than other tone digital modes though, and never claims a bandwidth larger than phone.

What is the definition of "spread spectrum" according to the FCC?

In what ways could ROS be considered spread spectrum?

What about ROS suggests that it's not spread spectrum?

The only page on ROS I've been able to find, http://rosmodem.wordpress.com/ , doesn't seem to have an in-depth explanation of what the mode is and does.

Comment: Can you site your source for your assertion that the FCC disallows this mode? When I look for one, I find a bunch of hearsay, and then the conversations end when someone cites a source that says it *is* allowed.

Comment: The FCC does not disallow this mode. Some statements from the FCC could be interpreted as allowing his mode, but they seem to keep their distance from a solid affirmation. He closest I've seen is http://www.arrl.org/news/fcc-reaffirms-statement-on-ros where the ARRL appears to neither agree nor disagree with the statement that it is spread spectrum. Still, I've edited the question slightly, and the title and three questions posed are still valid without asking for the FCC or ARRL opinion on the legality of the mode.

Comment: I'm studying for Extra now and the study material states that spread spectrum transmissions are allowed above 222Mhz, with a maximum output of 10W.  I don't think he's asserting that the FCC disallows the mode, but they do disallow spread spectrum transmissions below 222Mhz. (my comment came between the OP edit and the OP comment above)

Comment: Worth noting here that as of 2015, there's very little limitation left in the US on spread spectrum. Mostly just record keeping, and it can't be used to obscure the meaning of a transmission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some consider ROS Modem Spread Spectrum because of statements on the author's website call it: Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum. It's worth noting that the author is European and in Europe, spread spectrum is allow on the HF bands. Undoubtedly, part of this is marketing.  Describing a new mode as Spread Spectrum gives it a more techy feel and spread spectrum is something that came out of the military, further increasing the cool factor.

The FCC's definition of Spread Spectrum:

> Spread spectrum techniques are emissions that use bandwidth-expansion modulation >techniques to intentionally spread the information transmitted over a wide bandwidth. At any frequency in the frequency segment or bandwidth the SS emission occupies, either the spectral power density of the transmitted signal is reduced to a comparatively low level or the duration of the transmitted signal is very brief.

Source: *WT Docket No. 10-62* **RM-11325** *REPORT AND ORDER*
Adopted: February 22, 2011 Released: March 4, 2011

The FCC's ruling on the matter simply reaffirms what SS is and where it's allowed.  They didn't rule that ROS *is* SS or not.  This probably has more to do with conflicting information and lack of clear guidance.  The author calls it SS, but examining the actual protocol reveals that it's not.  It's not very popular in the US (largely due to this conflict) and so the FCC didn't have the number of opinions it usually gets when considering a ruling.

To lump the remaining two questions together:

It's not spread spectrum; it doesn’t hop the VFO frequency. It is simply FSKs according to a programmable algorithm, and it meets the infamous 1kHz shift 300 baud rule (FCC §97.307(f)3):

> Only a RTTY or data emission using a specified digital code listed in §97.309(a) of this part may be transmitted. The symbol rate must not exceed 300 bauds, or for frequency-shift keying, the frequency shift between mark and space must not exceed 1 kHz.

Digging into it further, ROS uses multiple tones over either a 2kHz or 500Hz bandwidth, (the frequencies for each mode/bandwidth are hard coded in the software). According to the rather thin documentation, ROS has three main speeds, 16 baud, 8 baud and 4 baud. There are some special modes, such as 7bd/100Hz for 136 and 502kHz (and 80m for some reason), plus an ‘EME’ mode for use on 2m and some other bands, for weak signal work as it has, in theory at least, the capability to decode signals that have a Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR) of -35dB, which is even lower than WSPR.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, several years ago I emailed a person at the FCC about this question.  I forgot her name but she was the person that replaced Riley Hollinsworth. She replied and said clearly to me that she considered it illegal.  She did not say that the FCC considered it SS and officially declared it illegal, she simply said that the author of ROS said it was SS, and therfore she was taking him at his word, and therefor it is illegal. I think she is wrong,  but you will really have to convince me this mode is SO GOOD that the benefits of using it outweigh the risks.

Comment: This would be a much more compelling answer if you could provide some references.

Answer (score 1):

Following  on from the  difficult  question
When is a  door  not  a  door ? ....When its a JAR

All  Ham data  modes that  pass  via SSB tx audio channel  are grouped under the  heading  of J2D..

How the  audio is  generated or decoded is of no interest  or than  is shares the  same generic title 'Spread Spectrum'  which , now  covers 'all aspects' of data processing  of this type , the  FCC  classed the  test modes  as  J2D , just  the  same as  Olivia , MFSK , JT65  WSPR, pactor or  any  other  audio  based  system

Nonsense based round  secrecy issues are flawed , as the  same  program's  are  available to all  stations, try decoding Olivia  , without the  correct  software , not possible , it therefore must be a  secret code ,  use any of the  available packages and it decodes  , therefore  its not  a secret  code...

So when is a mode  secret and SS ?

Ans  Not  when  everyone  has the  same software  and it  passes  via  SSB sound  channel

Simple

So can we  all  get  back to  qrp  dxing on the  same  qrg  again ?

To quote the  part-97

The FCC issued STA to test Spread Spectrum , for Ros and Chip64

If you look up the FCC website you'll see the interesting thing about the STA is the Emission Designator classification that was used - J2D

Modes which that have that designation are by the FCC's own definition NOT "SS emissions". J2D modes are already permitted on HF.

This sounds like people have been doing what we have done, taken SS to mean an abbreviation for Spread Spectrum when in fact the FCC's definitions are clear that the two are not the same. J2D is not SS (SS emissions would be specified as JXX) J2D is covered under the Section 97.3 Federal definition for Data.

As you know the FCC regulates Amateur Radio transmissions by what might be called "Content Type". The definitions for CW, Voice, Image, Data, SS etc are all in Section 97.3 at http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title47-vol5/xml/CFR-2011-title47-vol5-sec97-3.xml

The Data definition says: 
(2) Data. Telemetry, telecommand and computer communications emissions having (i) designators with A, C, D, F, G, H, J or R as the first symbol, 1 as the second symbol, and D as the third symbol; (ii) emission J2D; and (iii) emissions A1C, F1C, F2C, J2C, and J3C having an occupied bandwidth of 500 Hz or less when transmitted on an amateur service frequency below 30 MHz. Only a digital code of a type specifically authorized in this part may be transmitted.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you had better, more specific and useful links (like, to this STA that you mention), and edited it to be shorter and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If it fits into SSB bandwidth it is not spread spectrum, and it does fit.

Answer (score 0):

Your lucky  anyone is actually posting on the  issue ,  links etc  below

J2D is audio  via  sound channel  ,  the  SS  the  part 97 is  directed  at  is base band [base  band  = ultra wide  band ]and even  defines the  PN number  generators taps to  ensure commonality..

1 Spread Spectrum   in a modern sense covers  now  as a group  heading  all  aspects of  data  processing and  bandwidth  is a design choice , just as Olivia  has various b/w options , still  uses  DSSS  Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum  , referring  to  the  Pseudo random number generator used to add redundancy to  the  data , nothing wrong  with  that  , been in use  for  10/15 years  now the  world  over .

2 ROS uses  modern techniques , that  utilise  Spread Spectrum  techniques within audio  bandwidths, offering  the  next  generation , low s/n high data  rate and multi qso access .   DSSS and  CDMA  , CDMA  as in  mobile  phones  allows  multiple  simultaneous access  to the  same  qrg , hence the  number of  qso's showing  on 14.103 , providing  the  MOST EFFICIENT USE OF BANDWIDTH  of  and  HAm data  mode , A topic that is dear to  the  congested band  uses in the  US ?  the  answer is  already in use  WW

3 The  SS  trials  ran  with  no  problems , however  due to  external  off  shore usa , influences , the  end  game was  never played  out  and the  situation  remains  frozen  in time .. if ever the  subject is  raised , the  flow  of nonsense reaches levels  that  even broke the yahoo  data  group , its owner posting  'Thanks for all  the  fish' as a last gasp for  reality , linked to the  number 42

http://www.arrl.org/news/fcc-grants-special-temporary-authority-for-amateur-spread-spectrum-experiments